# Difference-in-Discontinuities Design

Tags: panel-data, econometrics, difference-in-difference, regression-discontinuity

Recently I came across the paper written by Grembi et al. (2016) and thought the methodology employed by them, Difference-in-Discontinuities Design (a combination of Regression Discontinuity and Difference-in-Difference), is very interesting. In their setting, all units were treated in the same year (2001). I have some questions:

1) Does anyone know about other papers/notes that deal with the technical details of Difference-in-Discontinuities Designs?

2) Assuming that instead of a regular Diff-in-Diff kind of setting here, I had a *staggered* Diff-in-Diff in which some of the units (the controls) aren't treated at all, how would one then proceed to create figures similar to their figure 1 (one can't take the difference between the pre- and post-treatment periods for all units, as not all units are treated at all)?

3) Moreover, would having a *staggered* Diff-in-Diff affect the decision of using a bandwidth estimator, or can the same bandwidth estimators that the paper uses (Ludwig and Miller (2007), Calonico et al. (2014)) be employed in the *staggered* Diff-in-Diff setting?

Thank you very much in advance!

---

GREMBI, Veronica; NANNICINI, Tommaso; TROIANO, Ugo. Do fiscal rules matter?. American Economic Journal: Applied Economics, 2016, vol. 8, no 3, p. 1-30.

LUDWIG, Jens; MILLER, Douglas L. Does Head Start improve children's life chances? Evidence from a regression discontinuity design. The Quarterly journal of economics, 2007, vol. 122, no 1, p. 159-208.

CALONICO, Sebastian; CATTANEO, Matias D.; TITIUNIK, Rocio. Robust nonparametric confidence intervals for regression‐discontinuity designs. Econometrica, 2014, vol. 82, no 6, p. 2295-2326.

Answer (score 0):

I just have an answer to (1):
Kyle Butts (2023). Geographic difference-in-discontinuities. Applied Economics Letters. Volume 30, 2023 - Issue 5. https://doi.org/10.1080/13504851.2021.2005236

Working paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.07406.pdf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/356563)